# How to create Crystal Reports with C# and sqlite?

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, crystal-reports

I want basic comprehensive guidance to start work with Crystal Reports, I have used C# with sqlite but never worked with Crystal Reports.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can download Crystal Reports for Visual Studio. This will allow you to design and make your reports, allow you pass data and setup access to your database. The Crystal Reports wizard will do most of the setup for you.